# No output in C++ program despite no errors and complete execution

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I wrote the following recursive program in C++ to sort an array using QuickSort Algorithm, but I am not getting any output(while I should have received output as space separated array because of cout) despite the program execution being completed.

I am relatively new to C++(not to programming) and wasn't able to find anything specific wrt my issue.

Please Help!!

CODE:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int partition(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = a[high];
    int x = low;
    int y = high;

    while (x < y)
    {
        do
        {
            x++;
        } while (a[x] <= pivot);
        do
        {
            y--;
        } while (a[y] > pivot);

        a[x] = a[x] + a[y];
        a[y] = a[x] - a[y];
        a[x] = a[x] - a[y];
    }

    a[x] = a[x] + a[high];
    a[high] = a[x] - a[high];
    a[x] = a[x] - a[high];

    return x;
}

void quickSort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int new_limit = partition(a, low, high);
        quickSort(a, low, new_limit);
        quickSort(a, new_limit + 1, high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int a[1001];
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    a[0] = -1001;

    quickSort(a, 0, n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Putting random cout statements, only the statements before the recursive quicksort calls within quicksort functions are returning output.

My Input:

```
7
8 7 14 6 98 5 4
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: If `a[0]` is your "size" but negative and your first values start at 1, shouldn't you set your `low` to `1` to skip that?

Comment: Why the `a[0] = -1001;` nonsense and the obfuscated "slow swap by arithmetic"?

Comment: What's the result of partitioning of a two-element subarray with values `2` and `7`? For example, at positions `low == 5` and `high == 6` in array of `..., 2, 7, 8, 11, 25...`.

Comment: Your program crashes for me when given the input "1 1". While you might argue that crashing is "completing execution", not many would accept that argument.

Comment: `<cstdio>`: yes. `<stdio.h>`: no. Both `<cstdio>` and `<stdio.h>`: why?

Comment: @sweenish removed it, not the source of the error

Comment: I know it's not. That's why it's a comment.

Comment: Consider `quickSort(a, 0, 1)` where `a = {-1001, 1}`. Partitioning will leave the array unchanged and return 1. The first thing you do after that is `quickSort(a, 0, 1)`, and then what do you think happens?

Comment: What's the  input of your program?

Comment: You should also try `cout << endl;` before `return 0;` (just in case).

Comment: Your `for` loops should go from zero to `n-1`, not `1` to `n`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  I put 0th element in my array as -1001 (theoretically -inf for quick sort) and took input of values from 1 to n

Comment: @user14812745: So you do - why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already place comments besides the bugs you made.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int partition(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = a[high];
    int x = low;
    int y = high - 1; // should be high - 1

    while (x <= y) // this must be less than or equal to account for x == y
    {
        while (x <= high - 1 && a[x] <= pivot) { // should use while loop instead of while do loop
            x++;
        }
        while (y >= low && a[y] > pivot) {
            y--;
        }
        if (x < y) { // swap only if the array has not been completely partitioned
            a[x] = a[x] + a[y]; 
            a[y] = a[x] - a[y];
            a[x] = a[x] - a[y];
        }
    }


    if (x != high){ // you must check x != high because of this obfuscated swap, think about why
        a[x] = a[x] + a[high]; 
        a[high] = a[x] - a[high];
        a[x] = a[x] - a[high];
    }

    return x;
}

void quickSort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int new_limit = partition(a, low, high);
        quickSort(a, low, new_limit - 1); // new_limit - 1 instead of new_limit
        quickSort(a, new_limit + 1, high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int a[1001];
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    a[0] = -1001;

    quickSort(a, 1, n); // pass index 1 in lower bound if you want don't want to use a[0]!

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output for your input:

```
4 5 6 7 8 14 98
```

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
    do
    {
        x++;
    } while (a[x] <= pivot);

    do
    {
        y--;
    } while (a[y] > pivot);
```

Is going to the moon and back. You are not checking boundaries in any way. You will corrupt the stack as soon as you try to write to the array using those indices.

This array:

```
int a[1001];
```

is not initialized. Therefore, it will be filled with undefined data, which will probably translate to coerce to integers bigger than x.

Last but not least:

```
 quickSort(a, 0, n);
```

You are passing n (the size of the array) as `high`, but you are using `high` to index the array.

here:

```
int pivot = a[high];
```

and here:

```
a[high] = a[x] - a[high];
```

This will also lead you to undefined behavior.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the problem with the 2 Do While Loops? I think they are the primary reason for the error

Comment: You don't make sure that x or y stay inside the bounds of the array. You probably want to make sure that `(x < y)` is always true in both of the do {} while loops and exit when that is no longer the case.